# automaically change div height with other

Tags: jquery, height

I have a div in my site named offers which has auto height . I have another div called promotions. I want to make a way that if I increase the height of the first div the second div will automatically change the height according to the first div. How can I do that? thanks

```
<div class="offers">


</div>


<div class="promotions">


</div>
```

Comment: The div needs to get the height of the other every time or just when the page loads?

Comment: The question is then what makes DIV height change? You have to be more specific regarding your issue

Comment: I need to add content inside the div. So the height will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ma51tap3/

```
var a = $('.offers').height()
```

**_increase the height of the first div the second div will automatically change the height _**

to check the sibling

```
$('.offers').siblings('.promotions').height(a)
```

OR to check the next

```
$('.offers').next('.promotions').height(a)
```

Comment: thanks it is working. But if I want to subtract some height from promotions div how can I do that. From eg. I want to decrease 300px from promotions div. How it is possible? Thanks